# Reshaping Dataframe in special form

Tags: r

I have a specific Data frame, lets say:

```
Site  Date   Start  End    Spec1 Spec2
ZR    10.05  10:40  11:40  X1
ZR    10.05  10:40  11:40  X2
ZR    10.05  10:40  11:40  X3
ZR    10.05  10:40  11:40        X1
ZR    10.05  10:40  11:40        X4
ZR    10.05  10:40  11:40        X5
```

In the End it should look like:

```
      ZR
Date  10.05
Start 10:40
End   11:40
Spec1 X1
Spec1 X2
Spec1 X3
Spec2 X1
Spec2 X4
Spec2 X5
```

Some has a good idea how to start? I am confused about the fact that I need a new row for every Spec1 and Spec2.

Test data:

```
structure(list(Site = c("ZR", "ZR", "ZR", "ZR", "ZR", "ZR"), 
    Date = c("10.05", "10.05", "10.05", "10.05", "10.05", "10.05"
    ), Start = c("10:40", "10:40", "10:40", "10:40", "10:40", 
    "10:40"), End = c("11:40", "11:40", "11:40", "11:40", "11:40", 
    "11:40"), Spec1 = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "", "", ""), Spec2 = c("", 
    "", "", "X1", "X2", "X3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Have you seen our answers? Do they help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have data for multiple sites in your actual data. Here's a generalized solution using `tidyverse`. Note that it is not possible to have duplicate rownames so I have turned them into a `variable` column in the output -

```
df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -Site) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  filter(value != "") %>% 
  rownames_to_column("id") %>% 
  spread(Site, value) %>%
  select(-id)

  variable    ZR
1     Date 10.05
2    Start 10:40
3      End 11:40
4    Spec1    X1
5    Spec1    X2
6    Spec1    X3
7    Spec2    X1
8    Spec2    X4
9    Spec2    X5
```

Comment: You could add to this a `column_to_rownames` at the end, since it looks like the OP has what's in `variable` as rownames instead

Comment: @camille wouldn't that give an error for duplicate rownames? or am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, my mistake. The way the OP has it formatted wouldn't actually work for rownames

Answer (score 0):

A (non-general!) solution to your problem would be

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(foo,key = Var, value=ZR, -Site) %>% 
 filter(ZR!="") %>% 
 select(-Site) %>% 
 distinct()

   Var    ZR
1  Date 10.05
2 Start 10:40
3   End 11:40
4 Spec1    X1
5 Spec1    X2
6 Spec1    X3
7 Spec2    X1
8 Spec2    X4
9 Spec2    X5
```

However, it seems to me as you would wish to have the Key variable as a row name (?). This does not really work as it contains duplicates. Moreover, I do not see a reason why you would want this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(melt(setDT(df1), id.var = "Site", 
               value.name = 'ZR'))[ZR != ''][, Site := NULL][]
#   variable    ZR
#1:     Date 10.05
#2:    Start 10:40
#3:      End 11:40
#4:    Spec1    X1
#5:    Spec1    X2
#6:    Spec1    X3
#7:    Spec2    X1
#8:    Spec2    X2
#9:    Spec2    X3
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can exploit the fact that there are unique values in the columns with `unique()` and `lapply()` which gives you a list. With an `do.call(rbind())` approach you can bind the rows of the lists together then. Similar with `do.call(c())` by concatenating which you need to transform into a matrix so that you can `rbind()` it with the first part. Like so:

```
var <- c(names(df1)[1:3], rep(names(df1)[5:6], each=3))
ZR <- rbind(do.call(rbind, lapply(df1[, 2:4], unique)),
            as.matrix(
              do.call(c, lapply(5:6, function(x) df1[, x][df1[, x] != ""])))
            )
out1 <- data.frame(var, ZR, row.names=NULL)
```

***Gives***

```
> out1
    var    ZR
1  Site 10.05
2  Date 10:40
3 Start 11:40
4 Spec1    X1
5 Spec1    X2
6 Spec1    X3
7 Spec2    X1
8 Spec2    X4
9 Spec2    X5
```

Or, if you don't need extra rows for every `Spec*` and rownames instead of `ID` variable, you could do

```
out2 <- data.frame(rbind(
  do.call(rbind, lapply(df1[, 2:4], unique)),
  do.call(rbind, lapply(5:6, function(x) paste0(df1[, x][df1[, x] != ""], collapse=", ")))
))
dimnames(out2) <- list(names(df1)[-1], df1[1,1])
```

***Gives***

```
> out2
              ZR
Date       10.05
Start      10:40
End        11:40
Spec1 X1, X2, X3
Spec2 X1, X4, X5
```